# MSVC: inference of pointer to member function with const and non-const overloads

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

This is a minimal example where MSVC can’t decide whether to use the const or non-const version of a member function:

```
struct A {
  int b() const;
  int& b();
};

template <typename T, typename Ref>
void set(A&, Ref (A::*)(), T);

int main() {
  auto a = A{};
  set(a, &A::b, 123);
}
```

The error message is

> error C2783: 'void set(A &,Ref (__cdecl A::* )(void),T)': could not deduce template argument for 'Ref'

GCC and Clang prefer the non-const method, and will compile this without problems. They would require `Ref (A::*)() const` to select the const version.

Is there any way to nudge MSVC into the right direction?

https://godbolt.org/z/ejT-Ls

Comment: fyi if you comment out `const` member function then MSVC will compile it - strange.  Live - https://godbolt.org/z/bZHjeO

Comment: Yeah, it seems like MSVC thinks the `const` function is somehow "viable enough" to make the function parameter type a non-deduced context, even though any actual attempt to use that `const` function there will correctly be rejected. It doesn't make that error if the overloads have different numbers of arguments or some invalid type matches like a pointer `P` and non-pointer `A`, but another form of probably the same bug: https://godbolt.org/z/S9LE8A

Comment: Changing the function parameter to `Reffed& (A::*)()` does help in this particular example. But that's not a very good solution in general, since it requires that the overload you want does in fact return a reference (and not some proxy object where `operator=` does what you want), and is the only overload that does return a reference (so will fail to distinguish between something like `std::string& name();` and `const std::string& name() const;`).

Comment: @aschepler that’s exactly my use case – the methods return a custom reference type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can force the non-const version to be selected by casting the  function pointer:

```
set(a, static_cast<int & (A::*)()>(&A::b), 123);
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. In reality, I have a series of methods that return custom `Ref<…>` instances. I was hoping to find a solution where I don’t have to spell all of these out.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this must be a bug in MSVC. You have a call to a function template, subject to template argument deduction. One parameter is of pointer to member function type, thus [[temp.deduct.call]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct.call#6) applies:

> When `P` is a function type, function pointer type, or pointer to member function type:
>
> - If the argument is an overload set containing one or more function templates, the parameter is treated as a non-deduced context.
> - If the argument is an overload set (not containing function templates), trial argument deduction is attempted using each of the members of the set. If deduction succeeds for only one of the overload set members, that member is used as the argument value for the deduction. If deduction succeeds for more than one member of the overload set the parameter is treated as a non-deduced context.

In your case, the argument is an overload set that does not contain any function templates. Thus, via [[temp.deduct.call]/6.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct.call#6.2), the compiler should attempt argument deduction with each of the methods. Argument deduction should succeed with only one method (the non-const one), which should then be the one picked for the function call.

@SoronelHaetir has already posted a workaround in his answer. I would suggest you [file a bugreport](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=62)…

Comment: And I don't see any way to apply SFINAE-type changes to `set` to allow the original castless syntax to work. The function parameter must remain deducible, making the function parameter more general like `MemFncT (A::*)` or just `MemFncPtr` does make the call truly ambiguous, and if MSVC thinks the overload set argument and function parameter type make the parameter type non-deduced, then any SFINAE checks anywhere outside the parameter type are too late to help.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of making this work is to switch the template parameters of `set` around, and specify the first with `decltype`:

```
template <typename Ref, typename T>
void set(A&, Ref (A::*)(), T);

set<decltype(A{}.b())>(a, &A::b, 123);
```

Answer (score 0):

For a workaround that doesn't affect the caller, you can deduce the class type and only enable the function when the deduced type is A.

```
#include <type_traits>

struct A {
    int b() const;
    int& b();
};

template <typename T, typename Ref, typename DeducedA,
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<DeducedA, A>::value, int>::type = 0>
void set(A&, Ref (DeducedA::*)(), T);

int main() {
    auto a = A{};
    set(a, &A::b, 123);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/GPxb9xaen

Comment: Reported to microsoft: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Type-deduction-for-return-type-of-pointe/1392983